# Water retention from medicines and obesity

Tags: obesity, edema

Some medicines cause "water retention".

I don't know how "general" such water retention can be, that is, if it effects all over the body or on specific organ/s.

According to Wikipedia, medicines causing water retention may be:

- [Hydralazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydralazine)
- [Fludrocortisone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fludrocortisone)
- [Mineralocorticoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineralocorticoid)

Is such "water retention" only generally-minor overweight due to [edema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edema) or can it somehow trigger obesity?

Comment: Obesity is excess fat, not water. It doesn't go away just because you pee off the water by using diuretics or simply limiting water intake. Are you're asking if water retention can actually cause you to gain fat?

Comment: @CareyGregory I ask if water retention, due to medicine, can trigger obesity (of fat) by any direct or indirect way.

Comment: For example, I assume that *maybe* excess water can cause some metabolic disturbances which results in obesity --- I don't have a clue if yes or no so I ask.

Answer (score 2):

The World Health Organization [defines](https://www.who.int/health-topics/obesity) obesity:

> Overweight and obesity are defined as abnormal or excessive fat accumulation that presents a risk to health. A body mass index (BMI) over 25 is considered overweight, and **over 30 is obese**.

The US Centers for Disease Control and Prevention [notes](https://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/adult_bmi/index.html) that the standard formula for BMI is:

> weight (kg) / [height (m)]<sup>2</sup>

Since BMI is proportional to weight, as weight increases, so too does BMI. Therefore, the side effect of water retention can cause BMI to rise. Should the individual's initial BMI be close enough to 30 kg/m<sup>2</sup>, this increase in mass could cause the individual's BMI to cross in to the obese range.

##### Thus, water retention can cause obesity in the strict sense of the definition.

Returning to the WHO's [guidance](https://www.who.int/health-topics/obesity#tab=tab_2):

> Overweight and obesity are major risk factors for a number of chronic diseases, including cardiovascular diseases such as heart disease and stroke, which are the leading causes of death worldwide. Being overweight can also lead to diabetes and its associated conditions, including blindness, limb amputations, and the need for dialysis. ... Carrying excess weight can lead to musculoskeletal disorders including osteoarthritis. Obesity is also associated with some cancers, including endometrial, breast, ovarian, prostate, liver, gallbladder, kidney and colon.

Of course, only a subset of these risks will increase from the additional mass of interstitial fluid.

Comment: Hello Ian, I think that the WHO's definition for the effects of obesity is demagogue in the level that it should be removed from the answer; I doubt anyone ever got blind from obesity; saying that people "may become blind from obesity" is saying like "a meteor can hit 1/4 of earth any moment now" or I don't know about a better comparison but really it's just demagogue that I can't allow myself to accept the answer, although I fully agree with the first part of the answer and with most of the second part of the answer. I mean Diabetes? Yes, high blood pressure? Yes, but blindness...

Comment: Unfortunately, obesity and the associated health problems are major problems in the US and the world. For a review on how obesity is linked to various eye pathologies, please see [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2698026/). There is no judgement in the answer, and I believe none to be present in the WHO guidelines, only facts backed up by hundreds of medical studies.

Comment: @botany_lover Diabetes can cause blindness, so anything that causes diabetes can lead to blindness, which is exactly what the WHO said.

Comment: CareyGregory I get the point and I believe that Ian should edit to put that logic there, also noting that this is not of the majority of cases or just rare (if its indeed rare, I don't know).

Comment: @botany_lover You seem quite certain it's a very rare thing, but according to [this](https://www.nei.nih.gov/learn-about-eye-health/eye-conditions-and-diseases/diabetic-retinopathy), it's not rare at all. _"Over time, more than half of people with diabetes will develop diabetic retinopathy."_

Comment: CareyGregory I don't know if most (51% or more) people with retinopathy become blind, I don't even know if most of them ever had obesity.

Comment: @botany_lover You can choose any interpretation you like, but clearly it's not the  extraordinarily rare thing you think it is. Your question was about water retention causing obesity, and it got a pretty good answer. So why are you disputing the facts surrounding obesity? I think you should accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory I don't "dispute the facts surrounding obesity" I was talking only about one thing which is the link between obesity and blindness; I never came across any good evidence to believe it's not rare; perhaps it's not rare in North America but in the rest of the world?, it may be *globally* rare. Furthermore, generally any diabetic person I have ever known isn't blind. I cannot accept an answer that says that obesity can cause blindness without any note that obesity-induced-blindness (not diabetes-induced-blindness) is rare or implausible at least due to available treatments.

Comment: @botany_lover 1) 80% of obese people become diabetic. 2) 50% of diabetics develop diabetic retinopathy. 3) I can't find numbers on the percentage of diabetic retinopathy patients who suffer severe vision loss, but let's say it's 5%.  So out of 1000 people, 1000 x 0.8 x 0.5 x .05 = 20 would go blind due to being obese. Those numbers aren't US only. In fact, I would expect US numbers to be lower than less developed countries. I don't think 20 per 1000 constitutes "rare" regardless of your anecdotal experience.